# planetary motion: Particle describes an ellipse as a central orbit about a focus

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, mathematical-astronomy, celestial-mechanics

> **A particle describes an ellipse as a central orbit about a focus. Show that the velocity at the end of the minor axis is the geometric mean between the greatest and least velocities.**

My attempt:

I am not sure that the elliptic path described under the inverse square law of distance or not. Is so, please give me idea how to identify?

If it is so, I know that $v^2=\mu \left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right)$ where $v$ is the velocity of the particle on the ellipse under attractive force $\frac{\mu}{r}$ at a distance $r$ from the center of force (the focus)and $a$ is the semi-major axis of the elliptic orbit.

Now the velocity at the end of minor axis = velocity at B, where B is end point of minor axis. But, if S be the focus and C be the center, then $SB^2=SC^2+BC^2=(ae)^2+b^2=a^2$ (since, $b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$). Therefore, $SB=a$.

Then, square of velocity at B = $V^2=\mu \left(\frac{2}{a}-\frac{1}{a}\right)=\frac{\mu}{a}$.

**Now how to find greatest and least velocities.**

Comment: If you want to quibble, nothing in the problem statement constrains the velocity as the particle follows the path.  This means the statement you are asked to prove is false. As long as the force is central, angular momentum is conserved.  Once you are given the ellipse (which I think you could use to justify an inverse square law) you can use that and angular momentum.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, I have considered the inverse square law. Would you please help me to solve the remaining part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kepler's first law states that:
$$\rho(\theta) = \frac{b^2}{a}\frac{1}{1-e\cos\theta}\tag{1}$$
and since the angular momentum $\rho^2\dot{\theta}$ is preserved (we have a central force) it follows that the speed $v = \rho\, \dot{\theta}$ satisfies:
$$ |v| = C\cdot\frac{a}{b^2}(1-e\cos\theta),\tag{2}$$
so the minimum and maximum speeds are given by $C\cdot\frac{a}{b^2}(1\mp e)$ (these speeds are attained in the endpoints of the major axis), while $\cos\theta$ in the endpoints of the minor axis equals $\frac{c}{a}=e$, so the claim follows from:
$$ (1-e)(1+e)=(1-e^2).\tag{3} $$

Comment: Then what is proof of the rest of the part? Please suggest in full.

Comment: @user1942348: the proof of what? The Kepler's first law of planetary motion?

Comment: @ JackD'Aurizio Proof of my question please.

Comment: Proof of my question please.

Comment: @user1942348: it is given in my answer, I cannot understand what more are you are asking.

Comment: $\text{(geometric mean between the greatest and least velocities})^2=\mu/a$. How to prove.

Comment: @user1942348: again, that is proved in my answer. The square of the geometric mean between $u$ and $v$ is just $uv$. The speed in the perihelion is some constant times $(1+e)$ by $(2)$,  while the speed in the aphelion is the same constant times $(1-e)$, always by $(2)$. Since the cosine of the angle between the major axis and the line through the focus and an endpoint of the minor axis is just the eccentricity of the orbit, $(3)$ proves your claim.

Comment: And trivially the maximum and minimum speed are attained in the endpoints of the major axis by the Kepler's first law or planetary motion or just because the angular momentum is preserved, so we just need to find the points on the ellipse for which the distance from a given focus has a maximum/minimum.

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot.