# Planetary Motion: A comet describe a parabola about the sun

Tags: geometry, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, mathematical-astronomy

> **A comet describe a parabola about the sun, show that the sum of the squares of the velocities at the extremities of a focal chord is constant.**

I have no idea how to solve. Please help.

I only know that if the velocity of the comet at a point on the parabola be $v$ then $v^2=\frac{2\mu}{r}$, $\mu$ is any positive constant.

Comment: When you tried to write down the sum of the squares of the velocities at the extremities of a focal chord, what did you get??

Comment: @rschwieb I do not understand your point.

Comment: I'm asking what you got when you tried to write that down. If you don't write that down, how would you finish the problem? Or did you have problems writing this down? We don't know until you tell us.

Comment: Does the comet go along the parabola like a planet does along the ellipse?

Comment: @zoli yes, comet go along the parabola.

Comment: @rschwieb I got nothing when I am writing. May be I don't understand your point. Sorry for not understanding.

Comment: ...but a planet not only goes along an ellipse; its speed is changing with time... (equal area swept through by the radii during equal time) Is this comet problem really so complicated? (A non-astronomer)

Comment: One thing first - do comets really travel on parabolas? If they did they would never return, and then they're not comets - think Rendezvous with Rama.

Comment: @mistermarko The question is as it is as given in the book. Before the comet leaves the parabola, it traversed an arc of the parabola, so at the ends of a focal chord, one may find the velocities.

Comment: They mean a 'non-periodic' comet. I've done an edit.

Comment: I have edited my attempt.

Comment: @mistermarko, yes you are right.

Comment: Jack provided a very good answer to your related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232744/planetary-motion-particle-describes-an-ellipse-as-a-central-orbit-about-a-focus/1232898#1232898), which you didn't even upvote (I did). You might consider being a little more gracious with the folks who are answering these questions.

Comment: @user1942348 The first step would be to (at least attempt) to write the thing down which the problem describes in words. If you are not willing to even *attempt* that or ask questions about how to do that, then I am voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the mass of the comet be $m$ and its angular momentum in describing the parabola of latus rectum $4a$, be $L$. Since it is under the influence of a central force, its angular momentum is constant. Let the velocities at points $P$ and $Q$ be $v_1$ and $v_2$ ; the solar radii be $d_1$ and $d_2$; and the angles that the velocities make with the solar radii be $\theta_1$ and $\theta _2$ respectively.

[image]

Looking at the figure, we can make out 2 things :

1. $\theta_2=90^\circ-\theta_1$
2. $d_1\sin\theta_1\tan\theta_1=d_2\sin\theta_2\implies d_2=d_1\tan^2\theta_1$

Also, due to some property of parabola, $\dfrac{d_1d_2}{d_1+d_2}=a\implies a=d_1\sin^2\theta_1$

Now if we add up the velocities' squares:
$$V=v_1^2+v_2^2=\left(\frac{L}{md_1\sin\theta_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{md_2\sin\theta_2}\right)^2=\frac{L^2}{m^2d_1^2\sin^2\theta_1}+\frac{L^2}{m^2d_2^2\sin^2\theta_2}$$
$$V=\frac{L^2}{m^2}\left( \frac{1}{d_1^2\sin^2\theta_1}+\frac{1}{d_2^2\cos^2\theta_1} \right)=\frac{L^2}{m^2}\left( \frac{1}{d_1^2\sin^2\theta_1}+\frac{1}{d_1^2\sin^2\theta_1\tan^2\theta_1} \right)$$
$$V=\frac{L^2}{m^2d_1^2\sin^2\theta_1}\left(1+\cot^2\theta_1\right)=\frac{L^2}{m^2d_1^2\sin^4\theta_1}=\frac{L^2}{a^2m^2}$$

Thus, we have shown that the sum of the squares of the velocities at the endpoints of a focal chord is equal to the square of the quotient of the  angular momentum and the product of the mass and the semi-semi-latus rectum. Which is a constant.